# Is it possible to setup ldap with external databases?

Tags: ldap

Suppose I have an existing ldap and I want to integrate users from one or more existing external databases under a dn called
dn: ou=users,dc=example,dc=com

Is that possible?

**EDIT:**

Maybe I was a bit to vague:
I have external databases containing users which have to be integrated into ldap. I want to do this without having to add them to the ldap database.

Comment: @downvoters I don't mind getting downvotes, but I expect at least a comment explayning why you are downvoting

Comment: @moderators how can this be off topic? depending on the answers I have eventually code something myself (for example extend the apacheDS functionality). I wanted to know if there is a best practice for integrating existing external user bases into ldap

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "integrating users" there. Is what you're trying to do something like this?

```
ldapsearch -h my.ldap.server -b ou=users,dc=example,dc=com "cn=somebody"
```

…where `my.ldap.server` is the LDAP server your applications are talking to, but the data you're seeking is on some other server under the naming context `ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`. And, you want `my.ldap.server` to interface with that server and bring the data? Transparent to your apps?

If that's the case, you can use an LDAP proxy which could relay the requests based on context rules. It can act as the single data source, providing a layer of abstraction between your LDAP clients and LDAP servers which may host different types of data.

Alternatively, you can use a virtual directory server product that can also act as a single data source. Virtual directory servers usually provide more features including support for multiple protocols, not just LDAP. They can also act as bridges which can interface with relational databases.

The first solution, LDAP Proxy, is usually quite sufficient if you are trying to virtualize only LDAP servers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have external databases containing users which have to be integrated into ldap. I want to do this without having to add them to the ldap database. Is there a standard way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm currently experimenting with apacheDS and writing a **custom partition** seems the way to go. Still reading...

Comment: sorry I just understood your answer :/ can you recommend a virtual directory server?

Comment: I like the one from Symlab. OctetString (which I had tried before it was acquired by Oracle) used to be good. I don't know if it's still up to the task.

Comment: have you ever tried apache syncope?

Comment: No, I haven't. Sorry.